# c++ read actual input line

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to get a string line from input. For example "This is great". In all cases I am getting either or "This" either " great". getline() method did not working as expected. Code tried:

```
string val;

while (true) {
    cout << message;
    getline(cin, val);
    if (val.length() <= length)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

My target is to get all sentence. Is that possible?

Comment: `getline` and `cin >>` don't mix well, because they handle newline characters differently. There are quite a few SO questions about it, I'm not really sure which to recommend, but for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6649852/1171191) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5739937/1171191).

Comment: Thanks, but solutions in links did not working. It is funny though that I am wasting hours for something so basic, that not working as it should be. No solution by far...

Comment: First you read a line with `getline(cin, val);`, then you overwrite `val` with a single word using `cin >> val`.

Comment: Is that suggestion, or?

Comment: No, that's what your code is doing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for note.

Comment: If you want to slurp an entire line into a single string, including consuming (and discarding) the trailing newline, use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). If you want to slurp a single word (contiguous sequence of non-whitespace characters) after skipping leading whitespace characters and stopping at the first encounter of any whitespace or end-of-stream-input, use [`operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). Pick *one* based on what your goal is.

Comment: It looks like you have edited your code without editing the rest of the question. Does the edited code still exhibits the **same** problem?

Comment: yes, this is same 100%

Comment: So which one is that? Are you getting "this", "is", "great" or something else?

Comment: First loop return empty and it goes to second loop

Comment: If I add cin.ignore() it works, but it deletes first letter from 2nd loop till end

Comment: for example I add three times "This is great". current code skips first one and goes to second loop. If I add cin.ignore() first tome works just fine, but  second and third output "his is great"

Comment: please provide [complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can reproduce

Comment: You need not call `cin.ignore` in a loop. Only after `cin>>` before `getline`.

Comment: @TeodorKolev if you want to answer someone in particular, use the @ convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding  `cin.clear(); cin.sync();` solve the problem

```
string val;

while (true) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << message;
    getline(cin, val);
    if (val.length() <= length)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more like sweeping your problem under the rug than solving it, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Well, I have describe what is my target. You did not provide any solution.

Comment: Solution to what exactly? Please provide a [mcve] in your question (it is off-topic and will be closed without one). No one can possibly know what your program fragment does out of context. If I guess correctly, you are doing `cin >> something` before the loop, in which case you have a solution mentioned more than once in the comments. Just read them.