# C++ file input problem

Tags: c++

Hi Guys! I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define MAXN 301

string names[MAXN];
vector<string> names_vec;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream fin(argv[1]);
    int n;
    fin>>n;
    string line;
    while(getline(fin, line))
        names_vec.push_back(line);
    for(int i=0; i<names_vec.size(); i++)
        cout<<names_vec[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and names.in file for input:

```
5
CLEOpatra
AISHWARYA rai
jOHn f. KeNNeDy
leonardo DA Vinci
tyleR durdeN
```

When i compile it and run it first prints empty line, that names_vec[0] is empty line. Can anyone explain why and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getline not asking for input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're mixing the `>>` operator with calls to `getline`. Generally, you want to use one or the other, but not both of them together.

The reason you get an empty string in your vector is because `>>` will NOT consume the whitespace which causes it to stop. That is, it reads the `"5"`, finds the newline character after it, and then stops, leaving the newline character in the `ifstream`.

Then, the call to `getline` encounters the newline character and immediately says, "Done! I read a line!". It consumes the newline character and returns the entire string leading up to it -- which in this case was the empty string.

If you know that your data will be formatted properly (no invalid input), it might be easiest just to use `>>` to read the entire file. Otherwise, I would recommend using `getline` to read each line one at a time, then using a `stringstream` object to parse the data out of the line.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that the rest of your input has first/last names separated by spaces. Since `>>` stops on spaces, it would probably be easiest to use `getline` to read the entire file. Example of reading the `5`:

```
string line;
getline(fin, line);

stringstream converter;
converter << line;

int n;
converter >> n;
```

Comment: @user: If you find the answer helpful, you should "accept" it by selecting the green arrow left of the answer.