# std::getline input not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, newline, getline, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744665/need-help-with-getline)
>   [getline not asking for input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input)

I am working on the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    string str;
    cin>>num;
    int points[num][2];
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nPoint"<<i<<":";
        getline (cin,str);
        points[i][0]=atoi(&str[0]);
        points[i][1]=atoi(&str[2]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\npoint"<<i<<" = "<<points[i][0]<<" "<<points[i][1];
    }
```

The problem with the above code that I am getting is when I enter the `num` value as some integer and then press enter, instead of printing...

"Point 0:"

...and waiting for me to enter it prints "Point 0:" and "Point 1:" and then takes the input for Point 1.

For point 0 it automatically takes input as 0 and 0.

Comment: `cin` leaves the newline character in the stream.

Comment: By "not proper" you mean like imput instead of input ? (-;

Comment: `error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array ‘points’`: Would you like to post your real code?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: That might be OP's *real* code,which perhaps the OP is compiling with an compiler extension which supports *Variable Length Arrays*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Prince John Wesley's reply, try

```
    cin >> num >> endl;
```

to flush the stream buffer before using it again.

Comment: Did you try this? What happened?

Comment: @Antrromet: Really? With which compiler?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I thought this should not compile too, but I have seen `cin >> endl;` used for this purpose before, though the solution you posted below is definitely safer.

Answer (score 1):

Your program hasn't consumed the newline after:

```
cin >> num;
```

The conventional way to do so is this:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

`numeric_limits` is defined in `<limits>`.