# input in c++ - cin.getline

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    char J[100], S[100];
    int count=0;
    cin >> T;

    while(T--)
    {
        cin.getline(J,100);

        cin.getline(S,100);
        puts(J);
        puts(S);

        for(int i=0; J[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; S[j]!='\0'; j++)
            {
                count++;
                for(int k=j; S[k]!='\0'; k++)
                    S[k]=S[k+1];
                break;
            }
         }
         cout << count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am taking input string in J,S but during execution of program it skips the second input from the console cin.getline 
I takes the test cases then takes the Strings J and S 
it takes J successfully but fails to get S string ?

Comment: `cin >> x` leaves a newline in the input buffer. Clear it out with `cin.ignore` if you're `getline`ing something afterwards.

Comment: and this is a 'c++' question, cin and getline aren't part of  'c'

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I re-tagged the question as recommended.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getline not asking for input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input)

Comment: The first thing you should do is forget that `cin.getline` exists at all, and instead use `std::getline(std::cin, your_string);` instead. It may or may not fix the problem you're seeing, but it'll definitely fix a lot.

Comment: @JerryCoffin the namespace scope getline requires the stream object to be in the 1st parameter.

Comment: @johnathon: oops. Quite right.

Comment: @JerryCoffin know whats even funnier, the OP is checking for null character but he's not initializing his array, compiler dependent on what it gets initialized with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be using a string , std::string, and calling getline as in

```
std::string s,j;
std::getline(std::cin,j);
std::getline(std::cin,s);
```

and then if you want to iterate over the contents of the strings by individual characters

```
for(auto i = std::begin(s); i != std::end(s); ++i)
{
     std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

use the iterators, and deference them to get the actual character values. Stay way from c strings as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
int T;
// ...
cin>>T;
```

...reads an `int` from standard input. To get it to read that `int`, you need to press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, but this code does *not* remove that <kbd>enter</kbd> from the input buffer. Then...

```
cin.getline(J,100);
```

This tries to read a string from the input buffer, up to the first new-line character. It removes that new-line from the input buffer, but does not include it as part of the string. As such, if you don't look really closely, it appears to do essentially nothing -- i.e., you end up with an empty string.

You generally want to stick to either field-oriented input (like your `cin >> T;` or else line-oriented input (`getline`). Mixing the two, however, can be a bit tricky, especially if the `getline` comes *after* the field-oriented input. Don't get me wrong: it *can* work -- and work perfectly well at that, but you need to know what you're doing, and even then it can still surprise you now and again.

As noted in my comment (and @johnathon's answer) you also generally want to use `std::getline` to read an `std::string`, instead of `std::cin.getline` with an array of char. The latter is clumsy to deal with, even at best.

My own preference is (as a rule) to use line-oriented input throughout if you're going to use it anywhere.

```
std::string temp;

std::getline(std::cin, temp);

int T = lexical_cast<int>(temp);

while (T--) {
   std::string j;

   std::getline(std::cin, j);

   // ...
```

As an aside, I'd also avoid using `T` as a name of an ordinary variable in C++. It's quite commonly used as the name of a template parameter; using it for "normal" variables is more likely to lead to confusion, especially for more advanced programmers who use templates more often.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Use getchar() between  cin>>T and while (T--)
as

```
int T;
char J[100] , S[100];
int count=0;
cin>>T;
getchar();
while(T--){
cin.getline(J,100);
cin.getline(S,100);
```

(2).
You can also resolve your problem in following way::

```
char  T[10];
char J[100] , S[100];
int count=0;
getline(T,10);

while((atoi(T))--){

cin.getline(J,100);

cin.getline(S,100);
```

use Any 1 of them ,it will fix your problem.