# Shopping cart assignment, concepts on getline()

Tags: c++

I've been working on a shopping cart assignment lately and couldn't understand why would this code below not work.

I have to write a code that will output name, cost and quantity of items, for three items without using arrays.

At the end of the maximum of three items I have to display out the total cost of the items. Currently I'm stuck because after I add in a second item, it appears that the program does not ask for the first input (Item name). Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int total;

  std::cout << "Item name:";
  std::string itemName;
  std::getline(std::cin,itemName);

  std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
  int cost;
  std::cin >> cost;

  std::cout << "Quantity:";
  int quantity;
  std::cin >> quantity;

  std::cout << "Do you want to add more items? (Y/N)";
  char option;
  std::cin >> option;

  if (option == 'y') {
    std::cout << "Item name:";
    std::string itemName2;
    std::getline(std::cin,itemName2);

    std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
    int cost2;
    std::cin >> cost2;

    std::cout << "Quantity:";
    int quantity2;
    std::cin >> quantity2;

    std::cout << "Do you want to add more items? (Y/N)";
    char option2;
    std::cin >> option2;

    if (option2 == 'y') {
      std::cout << "Item name:";
      std::string itemName3;
      std::getline(std::cin,itemName3);

      std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
      int cost3;
      std::cin >> cost3;

      std::cout << "Quantity:";
      int quantity3;
      std::cin >> quantity3;

      total = cost*quantity + cost2*quantity2 + cost3*quantity3;
      std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
    }
    else {
      total = cost*quantity + cost2*quantity2;
      std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
    }
  }
  else {
    total = cost*quantity;
    std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After I input 'y' after every item input, the code would somehow skip my input for itemName and output the 'Cost(in cents):' together with 'Item name:' in the same line.

I do think that it's got something to do with the getline() function, but I do not know exactly what. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getline not asking for input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frsitly, you are using `getline` and haven't included `<string>` header file.

2ndly, you may be facing issue because of `cin` buffer. you should use `cin.ignore()` after taking input for `option` for extracting the characters and discarding or other option may be clearing `cin` buffer.

`cin.ignore()` will work for ignoring 1 character in stream.
you can try `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` 
This will extract as many characters till ``\n''

---

***I tried following code on VS2012, and it worked properly.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
int total;

std::cout << "Item name:";
std::string itemName;
std::getline(std::cin,itemName);

std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
int cost;
std::cin >> cost;

std::cout << "Quantity:";
int quantity;
std::cin >> quantity;

std::cout << "Do you want to add more items? (Y/N)";
char option;
std::cin >> option;
std::cin.ignore();

if (option == 'y') {
std::cout << "Item name:";
std::string itemName2;
std::getline(std::cin,itemName2);

std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
int cost2;
std::cin >> cost2;

std::cout << "Quantity:";
int quantity2;
std::cin >> quantity2;

std::cout << "Do you want to add more items? (Y/N)";
char option2;
std::cin >> option2;
  std::cin.ignore();

if (option2 == 'y') {
  std::cout << "Item name:";
  std::string itemName3;
  std::getline(std::cin,itemName3);

  std::cout << "Cost(in cents):";
  int cost3;
  std::cin >> cost3;
  std::cout << "Quantity:";
  int quantity3;
  std::cin >> quantity3;

  total = cost*quantity + cost2*quantity2 + cost3*quantity3;

  std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
}
  else {
  total = cost*quantity + cost2*quantity2;
  std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
}
}
else {
total = cost*quantity;
std::cout << "Total value:" << total;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

---

For details on `cin.ignore()` [see this link.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

For remove `\n`, remained after inputting `option`.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does this exactly do? Sorry I'm still quite new to C++.

Comment: @xbili, you could read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score -1):

you can do:
**std:cin>>itemName**

instead of doing:
**std::getline(std::cin,itemName)**

**This would be the easiest approach for the strings without spaces!**

Comment: That's not a good approach for string input since it will not work properly if white space comes in string.