# How to get the dimensions of a 2d dynamic array of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a dynamically populated array of strings in C++:

```
string** A;
```

it is populated like this:

```
A = new string*[size1];
```

and then:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
{
    A[i] = new string[size2];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
        A[i][j] = whatever[j];
    }
}
```

elsewhere, I want to find out the dimensions (size1 and size2).
I tries using this:

```
sizeof(A[i]) / sizeof(A[i][0])
```

but it doesn't work.
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using std::vector?

Comment: You have them already: `size1` and `size2`. You don't need to "get" them. And you can't get them from `A`, which is just a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see where you're coming from, but this is quite a far-fetched duplicate. Won't help us convince people that C and C++ are not the same language. Edit : [C++ duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361663/how-to-get-size-c-dynamic-array).

Comment: @Quentin on the other hand that is a pretty horrible question

Comment: @MattMcNabb found it through [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008755/how-to-get-size-of-dynamic-array-in-c). I'm not sure which one should be chosen.

Comment: @Quentin personally I'd link to that last one of yours, and unlink that one from the horrible one :) (perhaps point the horrible one back at that one)

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I actually intended to post a c++ duplicate. Thanks. I'll re-open, but someone else will have to close with the better duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate memory via `new T[N]`, the value `N` is not stored anywhere . If you need to know it later, you will need to keep track of it in your code.

There are pre-existing classes for allocating memory that also remember the length that was allocated. In your code:

```
vector<vector<string>> A(size1, vector<string>(size2));
// (code to populate...)
```

then you can access `A.size()` to get `size1`, and `A[0].size()` to get `size2`.

If the dimensions are known at compile-time you may use `array` instead of `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to find the size of a two dimensional (more exactly of one-dimensional dynamically allocated arrays) array. Just declare it like

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> A;
```

and use

```
std::cout << A.size() << std::endl;
```

As for your approach then you have to store the sizes in some variables when the array is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning C++, I would recommend that you learn Classes. With a class you can encapsulate `int` variables along with your 2D array that you can use to store the dimensions of your array. For example:

```
class 2Darray{
 string **array;
 int rows;
 int cols;
}
```

You can then get the dimensions of your 2Darray object anytime by reading these member variables.

`vectors` will do this for you behind the scenes but its good for you to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an array just using pointer operator. Every array is basically a pointer with allocated memory. That's why compiler wants constant before creating array.

Basically; `sizeof(A[i])` won't give you the size of array. Because `sizeof()` function will return the a pointers size which is points to A[i] location. `sizeof(A[i]) / sizeof(A[i][1])` will probably give you 1 because you are basically doing `sizeof(int)/sizeof(int*)`

So you need to store the boundary yourself or use vectors. I would prefer vectors.

Answer (score -2):

Can't get array dimensions through pointer(s)

Comment: Bit short. Not great.

Comment: Can't find use in answer

Comment: You accidentally some words