# why cin is skipped in C++?

Tags: c++, stream, buffer, cin

I have a simple question but
any one makes me known.
below there is simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 string ans;
 while(true){
  cin >> ans;
  cout << "ans : " << ans << endl;
 }
}
```

I type `usa canada england island` and enter !!

It shows result below

```
usa canada england island

ans : usa

ans : canada

ans : england

ans : island

hello world

ans : hello

ans : world
```

Why does it skip second `cin` ??
How does it work in stream buffer?

Please answer my question thank you

Comment: Is your question "I enter multiple words, separated by spaces and `cin` is skipped for all those words entered? Are you expecting it to print "usa canada england island" first, then "hello world". You should clarify your question, it's a little difficult to read.

Comment: I have to agree with Tas, you should clarify your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program skips second cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390059/program-skips-second-cin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) if your goal is to output the all the inputs they entered rather than each item being seperated.

```
int main(){
  string ans;
  while(true){
    getline(cin, ans);
    cout << "ans : " << ans << endl;
  }
}
```