# getline() gets bypassed without proper user input the first time

Tags: c++, string, getline, cin

```
cout << "Type in your third message below:\n";
getline(cin, msgth);
if (msgth.length() > 0 && msgth.length() < 500) {}
else 
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Your message has to be between 1 and 500 characters long...";
    goto prot;
}
```

So, whenever I get to this piece of code, it's like it automatically presses return, and "skips" the getline() function (AKA, goes to the `prot` label). The same thing happens further up for some reason. However, after a bit of experimenting, I've found out that when using this:

```
input:
if (special == 0)
{
    cout << "Choose your input message below:\n";
    getline(cin, inp);
    if (inp.length() > 0 && inp.length() < 500) {}
    else 
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Your message needs to be between 1 and 500 characters long\n";
        goto input;
    }
}
```

It does work the second time (with other words, after going to the `input` label). The difference between these two codes is that the first one has to bypass a `std::cin` code before getting back to `getline()`, while the other one doesn't.
A solution and some explaination would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: goto makes code hard to understand/follow. Basically don't use it.

Comment: Never use goto.  That's what.  But that's not causing your issue.

Comment: Actually, I like using it a lot. However, I'll go a head and add a non-goto based example aswell.

Comment: @Max You may like using it, and you may understand what you're using, but other people won't.

Comment: @Max Don't sweat it, leave the question as it is. Still, bear in mind that `goto` is very rarely the right tool for the job and it's frowned upon by most people. Anyway, the answer to your question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input).

Comment: Okay, I'll leave it as it is. Was just worried of that people wouldn't understand. Regardless, enough of `goto`...

Comment: Do you use `cin` with `operator>>` somewhere before this code? i.e. `cin >> something;`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str;
start:
  std::cout << "prompt:\n";
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  if (0 < str.length() && str.length() < 20) {}
  else {
    std::cout << "invalid.\n";
    goto start;
  }
  std::cout << "input: \"" << str << "\"\n";
}
```

How is yours different from this?